# Jenkins + bitbucket and jira integration

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, jira

When clicking a "merge pull request to develop branch" i have to go to jira and check if fix version of this issue in jira. If its not the same in params throw an error and cancel merge? how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an integration for this. You will likely have to build the whole thing manually.

In our case we simply look at the fixed version and if it is not filled, comment on the pull request informing that the fixed version is not available. If you want to restrict merging you will have to go for a complicated solution where you add a new pipeline in Jenkins that continually checks all PRs alongside their related Jira issues. If the fixed version is filled properly, then set the "build status" in the Bitbucket PR to successful. Then, you can require a build to have run successfully for the merge option to enable. If you already have a PR build, you can enable to option to check for 2 successful builds (and so on).